# How can I resolve "Access of undefined property JSON?"

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxmlc

This should be simple, but google has failed me (more likely I didn't ask it nicely).

Using FlexBuilder 3, I just added code to do some JSON stuff. When I compile/debug from FlexBuilder everything works wonderful. When I try to compile using MXMLC I get the error "Access of undefined property JSON."

Some details;

In FlexBuilder I am using SDK - Flex 3.5.

The compile command line is:

```
mxmlc -load-externs=report.xml -warnings=false myModule.mxml
```

The import in the module is:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
```

I suspect it is a library I need to include on the command line, but it eludes me.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Phantom helped me figure out the mystery. I already had the as3corelib swc file in my library path in FlexBuilder, and in the compile of the main application of the system, but I did not have it in the compile of the modules, of which this is one.

When I initially tried to fix it I used;

```
-library-path="I:\MyApp\libs"
```

which caused other errors, when I changed it to;

```
-library-path+="I:\MyApp\libs"
```

Everything worked swimmingly. Please note th "+" before the "=".

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago the ActionScript 3 standard library didn't include a native JSON parser and we had to import an external one manually. Nowadays the AS3 standard library has a prebuilt one that works almost exactly the same.

You have two options:

1. Download the [as3corelib swc](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/downloads) and put it into your `libs` folder inside your project.
2. Overlay a recent version of the AIR SDK into your Flex SDK.

For the second step you need to download the AIR SDK from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html), be very careful with the version you download. You need to download the AIR SDK for Flex developers.

Your Flex SDK is located inside the `sdks` folder where Flex Builder is installed.

Once you download it, unzip it and merge all its contents with your Flex SDK folder (if asked to overwrite, choose Yes).

Don't forget to make a backup of your Flex SDK incase something goes wrong.

Comment: Mr. Phantom, The bit that is confusing to me is why does it work when I compile from FlexBuilder? 

Doesn't that indicate that I already have the library somewhere?

Comment: I see you figured it out. I'm not used to manually build my projects but it's good to know how to include the libs.

Comment: We have a number of systems that we work on. They all have a main application and many (50-100 or more) modules that are loaded and unloaded. We have two CMD files that build the main application and another to build any individual module. Never needed the libraries in the individual module before. I do have an alternative which would be to add the import to the main module.

Comment: Mr. Phantom, you were the person that gave me the file name as3corelib.swc, which allowed me to search for the file. Once I found the file I saw how I was referencing it (actually the path it was in), and added it to build command. Thanks.